# How to decide a buffer's size

Tags: c, file, malloc, buffer

I have a program which it's purpose is to read from some input text file,filter all chars which are printable (i.e., ASCII between 32 and 126) into some other output text file.

I also get as an argument "DataAmount"-which means whats the amount of data I need to read-May be 1B,1K,1M,1G,80000B, etc.(Any natural number can be before the unit).

**It is NOT the size of the input file,it is how much I need to read from the input file.And if the input file is smaller than the DataAmount,I need to re read the file,untill I read exactly DataAmount bytes.**

For the filtering,I read from the input file into some buffer.I filter from the buffer into some other buffer the printable chars,and write from that buffer to the output file(both buffers are in the same size).

Ther question is,how can I decide what size is the best for those two buffers,so there will be a minimal calls for read() and write()?

(NOTE: I won't write the whole data in one time since it may be too big,and I won't write each byte at a time.I write from the outbuff to the output file only when the buffer is full).

At the moment,I build the buffer size only depends on the unit:

If it's B or K,the size will be 1024.

If it's M or G,the size will be 4096.

This is not good at all,since for 1B and 100000B I'll have the same size of the buffer.

How can I improve this?

Comment: What is wrong with always using 4096?

Comment: @jxh If my input is 1B,it's way too big..

Comment: I'd go with 4096 bytes. It's the [standard size of physical blocks on most machines nowadays](http://pclt.sites.yale.edu/blog/2010/03/10/disk-block-size), so this will minimize the number of times you have to actually access the disk. The overhead for smaller files is utterly negligible.

Comment: @ChikChak: So, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @jxh Don't you think it's too big?How come it makes sense to treat 1B the same as 100000B?

Comment: No.  Unless you're on a RAM-constrained embedded controller, or the like, Just use page size and be done with.

Comment: @ChikChak: I think there is little advantage to knowing the size of the input ahead of time. Since I can't take advantage of it, it is simpler to treat all sizes the same.

Comment: @jxh Why would the size of the input file even matter to me?

Comment: My magical interpreter says: `DataAmount` means *input size*.

Comment: @jxh Sorry for not being clear,It is how the question was phrased,edited.

Answer (score 3):

My personal experience is that the buffer size does not matter much as long as you are using a few kilobytes.

As you noted in your question, there is overhead in doing system calls, so doing I/O one character at a time is not terribly efficient, and you can cut that overhead down by reading and writing larger blocks.  However, there are other things that take time, and any reasonable amount of buffering will drop your system call overhead down to the point where it is the other other things that are taking most of the time.  At that point larger buffers do not make the program significantly faster.  There are also problems with making a buffer too large, so you can err in that direction too.

I would not make the buffer size dynamic as you are doing.  It introduces needless complexity into the program.  You can verify that by running your program with different buffer sizes, and see what kind of difference it makes.

As for the actual value to use, the stdio.h header file defines the macro BUFSIZ which is the default size for stdio buffers.  That macro is a reasonable size to use.

Also note that if you are using the stdio functions to do your I/O, they already provide buffering (if you're not calling the system calls read() and write() directly, you're using stdio.)  There isn't really a reason to buffer the data twice, so you can either do the I/O one character at a time and let the stdio buffers take care of it for you, or disable the stdio buffering with setvbuf().

Answer (score 0):

If you know the input previously you can to some statistics and get the average, so it's not a fixed size but an approximation.

But I recommend to you: don't worry about `read` and `close` syscalls. If you read a very little data from the imput and your buffer is high, you waste some bytes. If you get a big input and have a little buffer, you only have to do some extra iterations.

A medium size for the buffer would be good. For example, 512.

Comment: Yes,but I don't want any extra unneeded calls and reads.I need minimal inetraction with the files.

Comment: Then you can create the buffer with the `DataAmount` value passed by args. You have a buffer's size a priori.

Answer (score 0):

Once you decide on the unit, then decide if the number of units needs extra buffer size. Thus, once you have found the *B*, check the value. That way you would not have to split the smaller units.

You can do a switch statement on the unit indicators, and then process within each case, based on the numeric value of that unit. As an example, for the *B* do an integer divide of the maximum and set the actual buffer size based on the result (again in a switch/case sequence).